Deltakernel FFI Error while DuckDb Reading Delta
Getting an FFI error while trying to read a detla table with Duckdb.  The delta table is on a network connected drive via SMB. I just wrote the delta table from the same machine, just prior, using the same python kernel.  I wrote the delta table using Polars and wanted to query it using SQL in Duckdb.
The error is here and I cannot figure it out.

IOException: IO Error: Hit DeltaKernel FFI error (from: While trying to read from delta table: '....\data\prices_delta/'): Hit error: 8 (ObjectStoreError) with message (Error interacting with object store: Generic URL error: Unable to recognise URL "file://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/airflow/data/prices_delta/")

Here's the code that I'm using to query the table.  Note that I've also tried absolute paths but the relative pathing works for other duckdb operations (scanning csv/parquet/etc) and I used the relative pathing to write the tables.
delta_data_folder = '..\\..\\data\\prices_delta'
Query = f"""
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM delta_scan('{delta_data_folder}')
    WHERE 1=1
        AND year = 2024
        AND month = 8
        AND day = 29
"""
con = duckdb.connect(database = ":memory:")
con.execute(Query).df().head()

